# How to install Android command line tools on linux server (Ubuntu)

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-ndk

I need [apkanalyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apkanalyzer) for my server application running in Docker. Does anyone know how to get the apkanalyzer without the GUI based Android Studio? If so, how can I install it please, is there any `apt-get` type way of getting it?

Comment: [Download the command-line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads) &mdash; see the "Command line tools only" section.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that, thank you! I am looking for some `apt-get` kind of an install, I'll update the question ...

Comment: Why would you trust a randomly repackaged copy of the SDK tools?

Comment: true :) .......

Answer (score 3):

Download the linux distribution of command line tools from here

[Download Android official command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools)

Then upload it to your server and extract the zip file then open tools/bin/ folder of extracted file

```
cd <extracted-folder>/tools/bin/
```

Now run

```
sudo ./apkanalyzer [global-options] subject verb [options] apk-file [apk-file2]
```